# Use the YouTube Analytics API to get moment-by-moment traffic

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am new to using the YouTube Analytics APIs and wanted to see how can I use it to fetch the data that I can then use to create a chart like this?

This chart shows the moment-by-moment organic traffic in my video i.e. how many times it was seen and when viewers started or stopped watching it.

I believe I would have to use some combination of the `views` metric ([link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics#View_Metrics)) and `elapsedVideoTimeRatio` ([link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/dimensions#Retention_Dimensions)) however I am unable to figure how it would look like and I'm not sure if they are even the correct metrics/dimensions.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

[image]